# image to the left of a text python docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I am trying to position an image on the left side of a text.

I found that it was possible using tables to position it, the problem is that the result I get is the following
[image]

and what I hope to get is something like that

[image]

this is my code

```
import docx
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
from docx.shared import Inches,Cm,Mm
import lorem

new_document = docx.Document()



table = new_document.add_table(rows=1,cols=2)

pic_cel = table.rows[0].cells[0].add_paragraph()
run = pic_cel.add_run()
run.add_picture("Image.jpg",width = Mm(45),height = Mm(45))

text = table.rows[0].cells
text[0].width = Inches(50)
text[1].text = 'kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk'
new_document.save("test.docx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WordprocessingML spec requires a table cell to have minumum content of one paragraph. Accordingly, a newly created table cell contains a single empty paragraph. This is what the extra white space above your picture is; the default empty paragraph.

Instead of adding a second paragraph, put the picture into the default first paragraph:

```
pic_cel = table.rows[0].cells[0].paragraphs[0]
```

The rest of your code should stay the same.